# Are emails sent from Apex recorded anywhere?

Tags: apex, email, governorlimits, logging

I am trying to determine the frequency of Apex emails to troubleshoot a limit issue

I can't find references to the emails sent from Apex (*Messaging.sendEmail / Messaging.SingleEmailMessage*) neither in the Email Logs nor by querying the EmailMessage object.

**Are emails sent from Apex recorded anywhere that I can view?**

It seems that the answer is that these are not recorded, but any more information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email logs should show this, but there's no way to distinguish between manually sent and code sent emails.

If SaveAsActivity is true, you could report on tasks, as they'd be stored there.

Unfortunately, unless you're doing your own logging, there's really no way to tell for sure if you're getting accurate numbers in any kind of report.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox SaveAsActivity is false on the one that I'm most interested in... I triggered the email to my own email address, and then retrieved Email Logs and queried Email Message object and I couldn't find my own email address in either...